# Insert into OLEDB VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, insert, oledb

What is wrong with this?

```
da.InsertCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert Into Table1 Values( 1, '" & TextBox1.Text & "')")
da.InsertCommand.Connection = con
con.Open()
da.Update(ds)
con.Close()
```

The database is never updated no matter what.
Or is there a better way to insert into db? I have tried the CommandBuilder but it doesnt seem to work as well.
Or can I directly execute a query on my database in VB.NET?

Comment: Use the command to execute instead of the data adapter, use parameters instead of concatenating the value directly into the command text, get the command from `con.CreateCommand` instead of creating it directly yourself, and dispose of the disposable objects (hint, use the `Using` statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a bit confused regarding on what DataAdapter.Update does. 
The Update works applying your InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand to every Added, Modified or Deleted rows present in your DataSource (supposing ds is a DataSet).
It doesn't add/delete/update a record to the database by itself.

If you want to add a record to the database you should write (pseudo)code like this

```
Using con = GetConnection()
Using cmd = new con.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Table1 Values( 1, ?)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textbox1.Text)
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

Note the use of the Using statement to be sure of closing and disposing the connection and the command. Also, never concatenate strings to build sql commands. Using parameters avoid parsing problems and SQLInjection attacks.

EDIT: Based on your comment below and supposing that the first column of the Table1 is an autonumber field you could change the code in this way

```
Using con = GetConnection()
Using cmd = new con.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Table1 Values(?)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textbox1.Text)
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

Also, for the problem for 'nothing has been added' I think you have the database file (mdb) included in your project and the property `Copy To The Output Directory`  set to `Copy Always`

See a detailed explanation on [MSDN at this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx)

Comment: No luck! I did as asked.
If within the same instance of the program i execute this method twice, I get a "cannot add due to duplicate primary key" error which suggests that values are being added to the DB.
But when I close the program and reopen it, or open the database separately, nothing has been added to it :(

Comment: This could be if your first column of Table1 is a primary key. Doing twice this command will try to insert the number 1 two times and of course this will fail if the first column is a primary key. If this first column is a autonumber then you should omit the 1 and let the database itself calculate the next value for the autonumber column

Comment: Is the "insert command" acting on some temporary database?? because if i exit the application and start again the data is gone.
And no data gets added to the database!!

Comment: Look at my updated answer. Check if you have a property called "Copy to the output directory" set to Copy Always for your MDB file.

Comment: Ok I get it!! So as it turns out, the data IS added to a temporary db which is generated in the debug folder.
Thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its because you havent tried to run your non-query. Remember, SELECT statement is a query statement while INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE are non-query statement. da.Update() or da.Fill() will only pull result from a query operation.

You need to add an extra line after you open the connection as da.ExecuteNonQuery() or any statement that executes a non-query statement in VB.NET!

~Shakir Shabbir

Comment: yes this does help in executing the query, but the problem is, when i fire up ms access to view the database, there is no information in it!

Answer (score 0):

Neat and tidy...

```
Using oCmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert Into Table1 Values(1, '" & TextBox1.Text & "')", con)
    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

It's a bit nasty because of the possibility of SQL Injection or Textbox1.Text containing single quotes but for test/dev purposes it'll work.

Comment: Someone has edited my answer but not to change it materially, - simply to mess around with the wording for some reason. Please don't. This is my answer and while you are perfectly entitled to correct it if it is wrong in some manner (it is not) I would appreciate it if you would leave it as is. You may dislike the wording but it is exactly as I intended. Changing it like that it is incredibly rude and more importantly completely unnecessary.