# Parameterized SQL query not working

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to get this query to work but it's not working:

```
strQuery = "Insert Into StudentInfo (StudentSurname, StudentNumber) Values (@Surname, @StudentNo) Where StudentName=@Name"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: whats not working?  INSERT queries dont have a WHERE clause

Comment: So how would I be able to insert the new StudentSurname and the new StudentNumber to the student with StudentName @Name ? Thank you

Comment: INSERT ==  add new record.  UPDATE == change existing data

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932095/insert-into-oledb-vb-net/13932693#13932693 which shows a sample of parameterized query.  This example uses "?" as a place-holder to 1 parameter, but you obviously have both surname and student.   Get rid of the where clause.

Comment: This is also not working:Update StudentInfo Set StudentSurname=@surname,studentnumber=@studentno where studentname=@name it says there is an error at "="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting new record, the WHERE clause doesn't make any sense. It isn't valid SQL syntax either.

You can try the following:

```
strQuery = "Insert Into StudentInfo (StudentName, StudentSurname, StudentNumber) Values (@Name, @Surname, @StudentNo)"
```

To update an existing record, use the UPDATE statement:

```
strQuery = "Update StudentInfo SET StudentName=@Name, StudentSurname=@Surname WHERE StudentNumber=@StudentNo"
```

The WHERE clause should have StudentNumber (instead of StudentName)  since that would be unique for each student. Names may be duplicate and would result in updating the wrong records.

Comment: Hi im pretty sure i need to do it with an update statement now. Could you correct this statement for me:             cmd.CommandText = (Update StudentInfo Set StudentSurname=@surname,studentnumber=@studentno where studentname=@name") it says incorrect syntax near "=" thanks

Comment: Updated with UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows performing an update using OleDb data provider, if you are working with SQL-Server change OleDb to SqlClient e.g. SqlConnection and SqlCommand. Note how the command text is set which requires Framework 3.5 or higher.

```
Public Sub UpdateRow(
    ByVal StudentSurname As String,
    ByVal StudentNumber As Integer,
    ByVal StudentName As String)

    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("", cn)
            cmd.CommandText =
                <SQL>
                    UPDATE StudentInfo 
                    SET 
                        StudentSurname = @StudentSurname,
                        StudentNumber = @StudentNumber 
                    WHERE 
                        StudentName = @StudentName
                </SQL>.Value

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentSurname", StudentSurname)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentNumber", StudentNumber)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", StudentName)

            cn.Open()

            Dim Affected As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())
            If Affected <> 1 Then
                ' we have a problem
            Else
                ' update successful
            End If

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```